# my jQuery code doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

so i'm trying to make an unordered list where you hover over one of them and it changes to the video,
this is my jQuery code:
btw, my jQuery code works, but just the iframe src change doesn't

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#qnaul li a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color" , "black");
    $(this).css("color" , "#c97c00");
    $('#ytplayer').attr('src', $(this).find('a').attr('href'));

}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color" , "#c97c00")
    $(this).css("color" , "black");

   });
});
```

my html:

```
<ul id="qnaul">
            <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 0px;height: 100px;" class="liclass"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vlZ7Log_uoE">1</a></li>
            <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 30px;" class="liclass"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AFdJzSGab-8">2</a></li>
            <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 30px;" class="liclass"><a href="">3</a></li>
            <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 90px;" class="liclass"><a href="">4</a></li>
            <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 30px;border: 0;" class="liclass"><a href="">5</a></li> 
        </ul>
```

my iframe:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" allowfullscreen="yes" src="" frameborder="0" style="margin-left: 400px;margin-bottom: 10px;background-color: black;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jQuery context is already the `<a>` element, so in order to extract the `href` you just need `this.href`.

Replace:

```
$('#ytplayer').attr('src', $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
```

With:

```
$('#ytplayer').attr('src', this.href);
```